# Jquery conflicts with jspm install

Tags: jquery, jspm

I have a problem with managing jquery while using two packages bootstrap and toaster.
- Bootstrap has a problem to work with jquery3.1
- when installing toaster with jspm it downloaded the jquery 3.1

Is there an option to tel jspm in the package.json to download jquery for it ,so it will use the one downloaded by bootstrap.

Thanks
in advance ...

Answer (score 3):

With JSPM 0.17-beta, you could used overrides inside your package.json file to map a dependency of *bootstrap* to a particular version.

See the documentation here: http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/overrides.html

It is also possible in your case that two different versions are being installed. In JSPM it is called a fork.

You can see the current forks by doing  `jspm inspect --forks`.
It is possible to specify a unique version by doing: `jspm resolve --only <registry>:<package>@<version>`.

See the documentation here: https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/installing-packages.md#inspecting-dependencies